# how to compare JSON object with a string in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Below is the code. The code works perfectly fine. It displays the content when both the EditText is left blank or has some string value that is available in the mysql database . My problem is that i want to display an error message when the **input** from the editText does not match with the JSON object or the **returnString** that store the result of the Mysql query after decoding **JSON**.

for eg if input='abi' //input from edittext

```
      khasi:abirt //khasi is column from the database with value abirt
```

output : khasi abirt will be displayed

but i want an error to be displayed when input does not match at all with any of the words from the *khasi* column of the database instead of a blank page activity.

for eg :  input='kljfldskfsldhf'

```
      khasi column does not consist the input word
```

outout : blank page activity

```
 String result;

 String returnString;// to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON

 String input;

 TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
      .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
      .penaltyLog().build());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_meaning);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        intent.setClass(DisplayMeaningActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        input =intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MEANING_INPUT);

         tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name "meaning" and its value submitted by user   
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  // define the parameter

     String response = null;

  // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
     try {
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
  "http://kffg.netii.net/konnect.php?name="+input, // your ip address if using localhost server
  postParameters);

 // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
String result = response.toString();

//parse json data
 try{
         returnString = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
         for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 Log.i("log_tag","ID: "+json_data.getInt("ID")+
                         ", Khasi: "+json_data.getString("Khasi")+
                         ", English: "+json_data.getString("English") 
                 );
               //Get an output to the screen

                 returnString += "\n\n" + "Kyntien  : " + json_data.getString("Khasi") + "\n"+ "Meaning: " + "\n"+ "" + json_data.getString("English");

         }


 }
 catch(JSONException e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Hi, curious to know where you found this code as I am trying to do something similar myself.

Answer (score 0):

need to use an if loop with `stringValue.contains("editTextvalue")` condition.
It'l be like:

```
if (inputString.contains(columnNames)) {
 //yes 
    } else {
//no, then print error
}
```

Since you already have your "result" in `String`, that shouldn't be a problem (?) .

Did not exactly understand the columns of the database issue but for the khasi column of your database, you can make an arrayList of of names and compare the string with a for each loop.

```
for(String string: columnNames){
  if(input.equals(name)){}
}
```

Maintain an arrayList where you add string for each time you get data for khasi like:

```
arrayList.add(json_data.getString("Khasi"));
```